# Execute php script outside of document root?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have the following directory structure:

```
/htdocs
     ├──test
     │     └──.htaccess
     └──myphp.php
```

`/htdocs` is root for `https://example.com` and `/htdocs/test` is root for `http://test.example.com`
My goal is to execute `myphp.php` script and pass filename as argument when client requests `./images/*` i.e. `https://example.com/test/images/blah.png` or `http://test.example.com/images/blah.png`

For this I'm using `mod-rewrite` in Apache2.4, I have the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ ../myphp.php?$1 [L]
```

This works great with `http://example.com/test/images/blah.png`, however I'm getting error 400 (bad request) with `http://test.example.com/images/blah.png`

```
[2022-05-28 14:36:10] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1888] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:9862] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[2022-05-28 14:36:10] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1888] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:9862] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[2022-05-28 14:36:10] [core:error] [pid 26880:tid 1888] [client 127.0.0.1:9862] AH00126: Invalid URI in request 'myfile.php' 'GET /images/blah.png HTTP/1.1'
[2022-05-28 14:36:10] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1896] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:9863] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer http://test.example.com/images/blah.png
[2022-05-28 14:36:10] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1896] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:9863] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer http://test.example.com/images/blah.png
```

If I try absolute path in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ /htdocs/myphp.php?$1 [L]
```

I get error 403 (forbidden):

```
[2022-05-28 14:39:02] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1908] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:2752] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[2022-05-28 14:39:02] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1908] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:2752] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[2022-05-28 14:39:02] [core:error] [pid 26880:tid 1908] (20023)The given path was above the root path: [client 127.0.0.1:2752] AH00127: Cannot map GET /images/blah.png HTTP/1.1 to file
[2022-05-28 14:39:02] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1908] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:2752] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer http://test.example.com/images/blah.png
[2022-05-28 14:39:02] [authz_core:debug] [pid 26880:tid 1908] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:2752] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer http://test.example.com/images/blah.png
```

Any suggestions how to make this work if possible without hard-coding domain names?

Comment: Try to increase [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and investigate the logs, to identify the cause of this error 400

Comment: I only get `Invalid URI in request` in the logs

Comment: To which level did you set the LogLevel?  I would use, at lease, debug, see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel

Comment: It set to `debug`. Added logs to the post.

Comment: What about using __DIR__ ?

Comment: @JoelCrypto sorry, DIR?

Comment: re-reading you r question, I have the following questions/remarks: "I'm getting error 400 (bad request) with http://test.example.com/images/blah.png".  In your directory structure `images/blah.png` is missing.

Comment: re-reading you r question, I have the following questions/remarks: When you say: "RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ /htdocs/test/myphp.php?$1 [L]"  I do not see `myphp.php` under the directory test.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure ALL information is correct, and complete.

Comment: In my structure I put `images/*.*` as in "any files". That part is actually irrelevant, as it's being overwritten by mod-rewrite anyway (at least it should) I've updated the question.